# Multiplicities of the Laplacian eigenvalues of a graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $\lambda^G_1 > \lambda^G_2 > \dots$ be the eigenvalues of the Laplacian matrix $G$ of a graph on $n$ vertices.

Let $\mu(G)$ be the composition $a_1,\dots,a_k$ of $n$ where $a_i$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda^G_i$.

Is $\mu$ surjective as a map from (finite) simple graphs to integer compositions?

Comment: It barely works for $n=3$!

Answer (score 2):

We can actually construct a graph with the desired composition of multiplicities by adding isolated vertices and taking complements:

As an initial remark, note that the smallest Laplacian eigenvalue of a graph $G$ is $0$ and that its multiplicity is $1$ if and only if $G$ is connected.

Let $(a_1,\dots,a_k)$ be the desired composition.  If $a_k > 1$, we can choose a graph $G$ with $\mu(G)=(a_1,\dots,a_{k-1},1)$ and add $a_k-1$ isolated vertices.

If $a_k = 1$, choose a graph $G$ with $\mu(G) = (a_{k-1},\dots,a_2, a_1+1)$.  Then the complement of $G$ has the desired multiplicities.

Comment: (For people like me who are a bit slow, regarding the last paragraph: since $a_1+1 > 1$, the graph $G$ is disconnected; hence its complement is connected; hence $\lambda_1^{G} < n$; and so indeed the complement of $G$ has the desired $\mu$.)

Comment: I believe it also follows from your argument that to get all the compositions we only need to consider threshold graphs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_graph

Comment: Note, interestingly, that the number of isomorphism classes of threshold graphs on $n$ vertices is $2^{n-1}$, the same as the number of compositions of $n$. I guess your construction gives a bijection between these sets.

Comment: This reminds me of "The critical group of a threshold graph" Hans Christianson and Victor Reiner.  Connection?

Comment: Theorem 5 of that paper (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(02)00252-5) says "The eigenvalues of L(G) for G a threshold graph are the column lengths of the Ferrers diagram of the degree sequence of G," which is directly related to your eigenvalues multiplicity question. They attribute that result to Merris (https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(94)90361-1). But I don't know if there's a direct connection to critical groups.

Comment: There's a simple bijection between (unlabeled) threshold graphs on $n$ vertices and binary sequences of length $n-1$: let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ be the vertices in increasing order of degree; then the $i$th letter is 1 if $v_{i+1}$ is adjacent to $v_i$ and 0 otherwise. Of course there's also a canonical bijection between compositions of $n$ and binary sequences of length $n-1$ (via "stars and bars"). But note that your eigenvalue multiplicity bijection is not the composition of these (think about $11\ldots 1$). But the aforementioned Theorem 5 still explains what's going on, I think.